# Having an issue with strong params during mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I'm trying to update multiple records with one form:

Here's the code in the view:

```
<%= form_for :product, :url => admin_products_update_multiple_path, :html => { :method => :put } do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Supplier Name </th>
        <th>Product Name </th>
      <th>type_name</th>
      <th>brand</th>
      <th>image</th>
    </tr>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= fields_for "product[]", product do |product_fields| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= product.supplier_name %> </td>
        <td><%= product.subcategory_name %> </td>
      <td><%= product_fields.text_field :type_name %></td>
      <td><%= product_fields.text_field :brand %></td>
      <td><%= product_fields.text_field :image %></td>
    </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

... and here's the controller action I'm calling to update:

```
  def update_multiple 
      params['product'].keys.each do |id|
        @product = Product.find(id.to_i)
        @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      end
      flash[:notice] = "Update products successfully"
      redirect_to(admin_products_path)
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:id, :type_name, :brand, :image)
  end
```

When I run the method, I'm getting a 'Unpermitted parameters' error showing all the ids it's trying to update. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you go into your logs and grab the output showing what parameters are being passed in?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/coffeejay/83168b035489eee0dd2ac1b464f957e5